# Constrained nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, maximum-likelihood

I am wondering what is the easiest/best way to find the values of $x_i$ that maximize the expression  $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \ln (x_i)$ under the constraints $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i = 1$ and $ 0\leq x_i \leq 1$

Do I have to use Lagrange multipliers? Is there an easier way?

By using the Lagrange multiplier and setting the derivative of the Lagrangian $\sum_i a_i\ln x_i + \lambda(1-\sum_i x_i)$ to 0 I arrive at the following conclusion:

\begin{align}
x_i=\frac{a_i}{\lambda} \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N \}
\end{align}

How would I proceed from that?

## Update: solution

By enforcing $\sum_i x_i = 1$ it follows that $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{\lambda} = 1$ which leads to $\lambda = \sum_i a_i$ and $x_i = \frac{a_i}{\sum_j a_j}$

Comment: Lagrange multipliers is very easy for this question, so there probably isn't an easier way.

Comment: I am trying to solve it with the Lagrange multipliers but, being quite inexperienced, I am stuck.

Comment: Read your notes carefully, and try to apply them here.

Comment: I added my progress to the post. I will be very grateful if you respond with some contribution

Comment: Good.  You are nearly there.  You need to find $\lambda$, then you will know $x_i$.  Try $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=1$

Comment: done! :) I hope it's correct

Comment: Go ahead and post your results *as an answer*. You'll get much-deserved points for both.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

By enforcing $\sum_i x_i = 1$ it follows that $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{\lambda} = 1$ which leads to $\lambda = \sum_i a_i$ and $x_i = \frac{a_i}{\sum_j a_j}$